# What is this SAS EG Error

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to run some SAS program to query a Oracle DB on SAS EG 9.3. The moment I run the code, I get this red underline and number 49. It doesn't even say "Error" to suspect some syntax errors. Below is a screenshot. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

A few lines of the code which gives this error:

```
%macro pre_network_roll(start);
%let start=%sysfunc(inputn(&start,anydtdte9.));
%let date=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(month,&start,0,e)),date9.));
```

[image]

Comment: I can't really tell what's going on, but it seems like you might have unbalanced quotes somewhere.

Comment: Its very intermittent. The same line of code give this error sometimes and runs fine sometime!

Comment: Very weird. Looks like problem in the wrapper code EG generates for you. I would try restarting EG to get a fresh session.

Comment: I did restart EG, restart the machine many times! No change!

Comment: Do you have comments in your macro text, and in particular do you use an apostrophe (perhaps for a contraction, like `don't`) in them?

Comment: No, I don't have anything like that. I have used a library in the first line -
LIBNAME ABC BASE "<path>". Even if I just select this line and Run Selection, I get the same error

Comment: It's just the libname statement that causes the error (when run in a fresh session)?  So if you remove that and run the rest of the code it doesn't occur?

Comment: The error occurs for rest of the code as well. I was just testing line by line to see if a particular line had a problem.

Comment: If you start a new session, and submit just the libname statement, you can get this error?  If so, I would check any custom autoexec or precode etc for an unmatched quote or similar. But would also work on making the problem reproducible with as small a piece of code as possible.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I created a new project and copy pasted the same code. It works fine now. The old project was on a network drive, maybe that was causing some long path issue or something.

Comment: I get this strange error whenever there is a single quote '  somewhere (usually in the comments). Sometimes, once it happens, you must completely close E.G. sessions - that means check your process manager for hung processes - before it will run correctly again.